# C++: How to implement sparse matrices with very large indices?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, sparse-matrix, eigen

I am trying to implement the dynamic programming presented in [this article](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/337) to solve the Shortest Hamiltonian Path problem.  This solution requires storing values in a 2d array called DP of size `n`x`2^n` where `n` is the number of nodes of the graph.

My graph has more than 100 nodes, but it is very sparse, so most of the elements of the matrix DP is +infinity. Therefore I can store it using a sparse matrix library (and see zero elements as +infinity). For example, using Eigen:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> M(n, 1 << n);
M.reserve(5e8); // reserve 4GB of RAM since I'm not able to estimate the number of non-zeros
```

However, the maximum index of this matrix is `2^n - 1` (in C++ code `2^n` is `1 << n`), which is far larger than what is allowed for an index (if `n = 100` for example). The operation `1 << n` is also no longer valid for very large `n` as well (I tried `cout<<(1 << n)<<endl;` and got 262144 as result for n = 114).

So, while the number of non-infinity elements of my matrix can fit into memory, I don't know how to deal with the indices.

I would appreciate a lot if somebody can help me to solve this problem. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: The [`SparseMatrix`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html) template has three template parameters, the third of which is the storage index type (by default `int`). You could just set it to `long`.

Comment: @HenriMenke OP used 2^100 as example of possible maximum index, which is way beyond the range of `long` of any platform I know.

Comment: @HenriMenke But according to this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/, `long` has the same max value as `int`. Even if it's larger I think it's still not enough for 2^100 :( Another problem when `n` is too large is that the operation `1 << n` is no longer valid. I tried `cout<<(1 << n)<<endl;` I got 262144 (where n = 114).

Comment: @Khue Note the "or greater", which applies on Linux and osx. Anyways, "greater" still is just 2^64.

Comment: That said, as usually, you can use boost. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html

Comment: What about using a map instead of a sparse matrix? Any key without a value could be assumed to be infinity

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks, but I'm not sure boost multi-precision can play with Eigen (or other) sparse matrix.

Comment: Dunno about Eigen, but in general, there's no reason why one shouldn't be able to use boost integers as indices in a sparse map.

Comment: @idontseethepoint Thanks. That is indeed an option. But I guess element access in map is not very efficient?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I see the idea, thanks. If using map, do you think using boost integers as keys better than using just double?

Comment: @Khue Definitely. After 2^53 or so, `double` starts rounding integers to other integers. That's bad when it's supposed to be an index. However, you are right that a map as in `std::map` will most likely be slow, probably even very much so.

Comment: For the keys you might make a new class that holds a vector of integers. Supposing the integers are 64 bit, the first value would be the first 64 bits of the number, the second int would be the second 64 bits and so on. std::unordered_map will probably be faster than std::map

Comment: @idontseethepoint Your first advice basically boils down to reimplementing some big integer type, which you shouldn't. There's even a decent chance boost will use some platform specific built in type, which is not beatable in software. For the second part: No, neither is a good implementation of a sparse matrix.

Comment: That depends on the relative amount of time that will be spent altering vs. reading the matrix, a map is efficient for changing the matrix

Comment: @idontseethepoint Even then, measure. The poor data locality of those containers really tends to mess stuff up performancewise.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Your comments are very valuable, thanks. What I need is a structure that can help me to efficiently insert new elements on the fly and at the same time check if certain elements exist. I'm thinking about this: instead of using a 2d structure, I use a vector with elements DP[i + N*s] where i go from 0 to n-1 and s go from 0 to 2^n - 1. I define another vector of indices `indices[]` for storing the indices of the non-infinity elements of `DP`. The values of indices are ordered, so finding an index takes O(log(L))...

Comment: Well after typing all of these I realized that it's just to naive. STL map should already be more efficient than that.

Comment: If inserting and checking for existing elements rather than iterating is the bulk of the work, the two standard map types are indeed worth a try. If one of them is fast enough, that's probably the easiest way to go.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks a lot! I'll get back about the performance.

Comment: (Tbh, I kinda regret talking about performance that much. Code for correctness first, optimize later. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen For me that was a good thing (at least for my problem) ;) A good analysis at the beginning will lead to the right direction.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731764/c-using-pair-of-cpp-int-int-integers-as-key-in-unordered-map-where-cpp-in Thank you so much!!